# How to exclude a string from capturing url pattern "named groups" Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I am trying to make urls pattern to catch all urls from root.

my main urls.py is:

```
path('', (include('myapp.urls', namespace='app1')
```

I am using two url patterns in app1.urls:

```
re_path(r'^(?P<url_var1>[-\w./]+)/$', DetailView1.as_view(), name='DetailView1'),
re_path(r'^(?P<url_var2>[-\w./]+)/$', DetailView2.as_view(), name='DetailView2'),
```

My views.py file is as:

```
class DetailView1(View):
    template_name = 'detail.html'
    def get(self, request, url_var1):
        obj1 = model1.objects.get(my_url=url_var1)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'obj1':obj1})

class DetailView2(View):
    template_name = 'detail.html'
    def get(self, request, url_var2):
        obj2 = model2.objects.get(my_url=url_var2)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'obj2':obj2})
```

when i request url "/first-post/my-first-post/", It checks out the url which is in my "model1" under ther header "my_url" and return the page.

But when I request url "/second-post/my-second-post/", It checks out the url in "model1" and throws an error, as the url is in "model2" under header "my_url".

I know that the urlpattern follows a squence check, and stops at the pattern which matches the first urlpattern(DetailView1), thats why It is giving me this error.

I want to know is there a way I can override this behavior of urlpattern.

I have also tried reverse, when url is not found in  DetailView1:

```
try:
    obj1 = model1.objects.get(my_url=url_var1)
except:
    return reverse('app1:DetailView2')
```

But Its still giving me an error.

If any of you got any other suggestions for catching urlpattern from root for mare than two type of urlpattern please tell me.

I am making a product cum blog website which has two models "model1" which is a product model, and "model2" which is a blog model. Now the "model1" is for automobile having 2 main categories "car" and "bike" and "model2" is having the same as "latest in cars" & "latest in bikes". For these categories I want to pick up urls from the root which have been given as "/cars/lexus.....", "/bike/ducati....". Also, there can be further additions of subfolder url and all urls have product IDs having "." and numbers. So is there is way i can pick urls frm root for both models using the above url pattern.

Comment: Does your requirement to use two database table for details view.? Why is that? Curious to know. If that's final then you have two options. One is to change the url pattern and then the second one is to check both model ( this will take time )

Comment: I have edited the post to explain my pratical problem, please go through it

Comment: Please consider to create single model for all your details.

Answer (score 3):

Its not possible to have multiple views and single urlpattern in Django.

Take a look at your views. They are almost the same. You should put the logic handling different url parameters in single view.

My advice would be also to carefully review your model design, it looks like you have two models that are essentially the same. I feel that this is the root of your problem.

Additionally I assume that you are trying to create some kind of blog.
Django had its beginning as framework powering news site. And it has some helpful tools. For example take a look at [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) This may provide you with functionality you are looking for. Without over complicating the urlpatterns.

Comment: I am making a product cum blog website which has two models "model1" which is a product model, and "model2" which is a blog model. Now the "model1" is for automobile having 2 main categories "car" and "bike" and "model2" is having the same as "latest in cars" & "latest in bikes". For these categories I want to pick up urls from the root which have been given as "/cars/lexus.....", "/bike/ducati....". Also, there can be further additions of subfolder url and all urls have product IDs having "." and numbers. So is there is way i can pick urls frm root for both models using the above url pattern.

Comment: No sir that is not a new problem, its just the practical perspective.